# UIVisualEffectView while UITableViewCell highlight to show a Popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I have a tableview and while tap and holding a cell, others should be blurred except the highlighted. You can see this feature in new WhatsApp. I don't know what's behind this UI changes.

[image: Sample of WhatsApp screenshot]

Comment: You are looking for context menus to do this - https://blog.apphud.com/context-menus/ is a good explanation of how to implement this in different situations.

Comment: OMG! I wasn't aware of this new concept introduced. You made my day!! Thanks

Comment: @darrenallen7 blog link is not working anymore... can you please share new link

Comment: Posting an updated link: https://apphud.com/blog/how-to-implement-context-menus-in-ios-13

Another alternate: https://medium.com/ivymobility-developers/context-menus-in-ios-226727a8aa88